# Parallel list reduction in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I am working through the Cuda Parallel reduction Whitepaper, but unfortunately my algorithm seems to repeatedly produce incorrect results, and I can not seem to figure out why(surely a textbook example must work? Surely I'm just doing something very obvious wrong?). Here is my kernel function:

**My define:**

```
 #define BLOCK_SIZE 512
```

**My Kernel function:**

```
 __global__ void total(float * inputList, float * outputList, int len) {
      __shared__ float sdata[2*BLOCK_SIZE];
      unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
      unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockDim.x*2) + threadIdx.x;
      sdata[t] = inputList[i]+inputList[i+blockDim.x];
      __syncthreads();
      for (unsigned int s=blockDim.x/2; s>0; s>>=1) {
        if (tid < s) {
          sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
      }
      if (tid == 0) 
        outputList[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

**My memory allocation:**

```
  outputSize = inputSize / (BLOCK_SIZE<<1);
  cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceInput, inputSize*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceOutput, outputSize*sizeof(float));
  cudaMemcpy(deviceInput, hostInput, inputSize*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

**My device call:**

```
 dim3 dimGrid((inputSize-1)/BLOCK_SIZE +1, 1, 1);
 dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,1,1);

 total<<<dimBlock, dimGrid>>>(deviceInput, deviceOutput, outputSize);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

**My memory fetch:**

```
 cudaMemcpy(hostOutput, deviceOutput, outputSize*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

And finally my final calculation:

```
 for (int counter = 1; counter < outputSize; counter++) {
    hostOutput[0] += hostOutput[counter];
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the kernel function input parameter `int len` seems never used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your kernel launch configuration in the following line of your code is incorrect.

```
total<<<dimBlock, dimGrid>>>(deviceInput, deviceOutput, outputSize);
```

The first argument of kernel configuration is the grid size and the second argument is the block size.

You should be doing this:

```
total<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(deviceInput, deviceOutput, outputSize);
```

Please always [perform error checking on CUDA Runtime function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038590/1231073) and check the returned error codes to get the reason for the failure of your program.

Your kernel launch should fail in your current code. An error checking on the `cudaDeviceSynchronize` call would have led you to the reason of incorrect results.

Comment: Good spot - this is *always* going to cause incorrect results. The assumption I mentioned in my answer only causes a problem for some cases...

Answer (score 3):

The code assumes the input size is a multiple of the block size. If inputSize is not a multiple of the block size, it will read off the end of the inputList array.